# I have issues making my bot copy the text then send it back

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I use `discord.js` and I am making a bot that sends back the text that a user types but whatever I try I run into problems.

This is what I tried:

```js
let s4 = (message.channel, message.content);

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command) {
        messege.channel.send(s1 + s4);
    }
});
```

Comment: What's going wrong? What errors are you getting? How did you use the `message` object before it was defined? Did you misspell the last `message` on purpose? What do you want help with specifically?

Comment: I got message not defined this time but I’m not sure if this code is right I’m new to js do you think the coding is right?

Comment: Where did you define the `s1` variable?

Comment: at the beggining I did other stuff too I only sent the message code

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

let s2 = 'https://terraria.gamepedia.com/'

let s4 = (message.channel, message.content)
    
    console.log('your bot name is online!');
})

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

       if(command){
         message.channel.send(s1 + s4);

    }           
}); 
client.login('private');

Comment: I took out some stuff cuz it was too long

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue is in

```
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command) {
    messege.channel.send(s1 + s4);
}
```

you are putting an array into in if statement with nothing to turn it into a Boolean. Another issue you might have is that the command is a constant. I suggest replacing it with

```
let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
messege.channel.send(s1 + s4);
```

Also, reading the comments, it looks like you referenced the message object before it was defined
In the future, please add the errors you are receiving to your question